# how to capture a key event for an emergency button implementation in lock screen state of android

Tags: android, menu, locking, keyevent, keyguard

I want it like:
Start an emergency activity on, say long press MENU button. Though there is a phone lock.
As this is an emergency, on long press MENU button, it will capture the key Event/press and will start the emergency activity defined by the developer.
but now the problem is,
when there is screen Lock, key-guard will be lock i.e it cant capture any key Event/Press in a phone lock state.

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: No, keys are not dispatched when the keyguard is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can't dispatch even when screen is lock but using accelero meter ie by shake u can open screen lock and do what ever u t ...even u start any thing in background